# MySQL Workbench - cannot manipulate users

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a problem with MySQL Workbench. I cannot add or edit users on the database. Since I can make changes via queries I believe it's not MySQL server related but limited to Workbench. I upgraded to the latest version but still the same. Anyone experienced something similar?

[image]

Comment: What's your MySQL server version? What's your Workbench version?

Comment: mysql:5.6.40 and workbench 8.0.25 (latest one)